# why unhandledrejection event not fired when chrome dev tools open

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

i have a handler for window unhandledrejection which handle all user fails. This handler works perfect until chrome dev tools is opened. If devtool open then event not fired and error message shown into console. This is very confuse me. I want to know why same code works different depending on dev tools open

this is my handler code

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (event)=> {
  alert(event.reason)
})
```

Comment: same here, did you find any solution?